# `the page is being unloaded` error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, routes

I was working with a NodeJS-ReactJS Isomorphic App, and when I click on a `Link` I'm getting an error saying

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request has been terminated
Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.`

The first two reasons (offline and CORS) I heard about. What is the `the page is being unloaded` error means? How it may cause the browser not navigating to need.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is your link pointing to an external domain ? If so then better use `a` tag.

Comment: I am using `a` tag inside `Link` component.

Comment: why would you do that! Use any one of them at a time.

Comment: I don't understand. It's a react component. This is how a component works..!

Answer (score 4):

Your Error is

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request has been terminated
```

This error is caused when the request in the promise is terminated before it is resolved or rejected. This can happen if (`Possible causes`)

1. `the network is offline` : There is a network failure and the connection to the url using which the request was being processed is lost.
2. `Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` : The request is rejected due to absence of proper CORS headers.
3. `the page is being unloaded` : The page making the request is closed before the request completed.

Of the above reasons, the most probable cause relevant to your case would be either 1 or 2, since you get the error on clicking a `Link` to navigate to a component. Please check the requests being made by the new component that is being loaded using the `Link`.

**Edit:**
If you look at the error message screen shot, it clearly states that the error occured at line no. 73194 of app.js at PromiseRequest in node_modules/superagent/lib/client.js.Request.crossDomainError. So the reason for your error is a CORS error which is described in number 2 above.

Comment: Thanks. My question is what is the third error/cause? What is `the page is being unloaded` error means? *request is closed before the request completed.* doesnt mean a page is *unloaded*. Am I right?

Comment: If the page making the request is closed before the request is completed, this is the error that you will get. When the page closes, it fires a `beforeunload`  and an `unload` event which lets the service know that the request can be terminated.

Comment: Oh..Thannks. But in my case, the second time I tried to navigate was working though. CORS was okay. And I can't see this error now in my project.

Answer (score 0):

'cause `Link` component is using `Location.push` to do the redirection, while `Location.push` method cannot redirect to another domain.

So my solutions are:

1. Use `window.open('http://your.new.domain.com/index', '_self')`
2. Use `<a href="http://your.new.domain.com/index">`

Answer (score -2):

It seems you have not enabled the cors in your node server.
Suggested Steps:

- npm install cors
- use it in app.js (node server)

.

```
var cors = require('cors');    
var app = express();
app.use(cors()); //Enable CORS
```